# Zend framework 1.7 forward req with error messages when input validation fails

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework

Using Zend 1.7 I am validating some data. If validation fails I `forward` to an other page.
Is possible to forward with error messages generated if input validation fails? 
Something like this:

```
public function postAction() {
        $newData = $this->getRequest ()->getPost ();
        $validators = array ('name' => array ('presence' => 'required'));

        $input = new Zend_Filter_Input(null, $validators);

        $input->setData($newData);
        if (!$input->isValid()) {
            print_r($input->getErrors());
            print_r($input->getMessages());

            //here I want to pass the Erros and the Messages 
            return $this->_forward('action', 'controller', 'module');
        }
    }
```

Comment: One of possibilities is to storage errors in session, disyplay them and then clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forth parameter of `forward()` can be used to pass parameters:

```
return $this->_forward(
  'action', 
  'controller', 
  'module', 
  array(
    'errors' => $input->getErrors(),
    'messages' => $input->getMessages()
  )
);
```

Although you shouldn't pass fully fledged Zend Framework objects.